# windows update broke windows subsystem for linux 2

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have been using Windows Subsystem for Linux 2, however after applying a Windows Update that had been waiting for a while, now when I open the Ubuntu terminal app, it is blank and I cannot type:

- After leaving it open, it eventually outputs:

  ```
  Installing, this may take a few minutes...

    WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80080005
    Error: 0x80080005 Server execution failed

    Press any key to continue...
  ```
- ```bsh
  ver&wsl --list --all -v

    Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1139]
    Server execution failed
  ```

I can't seem to find any information on it yet; does anyone have any idea what to do about this?

Comment: Please share `cmd` commands output `ver&wsl --list --all -v` via the [edit] button.

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Try `Win+R` => `optionalfeatures.exe`, untick _Windows Subsystem for Linux_ and click `OK`; after restart (if prompted), check it back via the same procedure.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Do you know why this fixed the issue? Could be useful for future ref.

Comment: What happens to the existing machines if you do the "reset"? @JosefZ or whoever has tried that...

Comment: @Albin - Nothing

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, so I figure with `nothing` you mean that you won't loose any existing linux VM/configruations/data by reinstalling it, right?

Answer (score 8):

As commented by [JosefZ](https://superuser.com/users/376602/josefz), following procedure fixes the issue:

- Run (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) `optionalfeatures.exe`
- untick Windows Subsystem for Linux and click `OK`
  Allow the system to restart if prompted
- Run (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) `optionalfeatures.exe` again
- tick Windows Subsystem for Linux and click `OK`

This will effectively uninstall the WSL and install it again.

The existing WSL installations seem not affected by this procedure in any way (they look exactly like before).

Comment: Had the same problem on Version 10.0.19042.1052 and this fixed it without killing the content of my WSL.